# Need solution on Child to parent if Parent values is changed to something else

Tags: apex, trigger, workflow, process-builder

I have a requirement where My custom Object(`Market__c`) is lookup of `Account` .
Whenever my `Account` type value is changed from `Inactive` to `Active` I Need to capture current date to(`Captureaccount__c`) `Market__c` object.

I am not able to write workflow because `ISCHANGED` is not allowed in child to parent.
Please suggest if you anyone have solution .

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a trigger on the account, on after update, check the type of account is changed or not. If yes capture today's date.